# JQuery Loop for ID's using the iteration number

Tags: jquery, for-loop, each

I have a very basic question but I couldn't find the answer anywhere maybe because I don't know what to search for exactly.

I inserted several read more buttons on my page. By clicking one, the read more text appears, the read more button disappears and a read less button appears.

To do this, this JQuery code works fine for me:

```
$('#readmore1').click(function(){
    $("#readmoretext1").toggle();
    $("#readmore1").hide();
    $("#readless1").show();
});

$('#readless1').click(function(){
    $("#readmoretext1").toggle();
    $("#readmore1").show();
    $("#readless1").hide();
});

$('#readmore2').click(function(){
    $("#readmoretext2").toggle();
    $("#readmore2").hide();
    $("#readless2").show();
});

$('#readless2').click(function(){
    $("#readmoretext2").toggle();
    $("#readmore2").show();
    $("#readless2").hide();
});
```

Since I do have some more buttons I wanted to do a loop so I don't have to copy the code everytime. The problem is that I (as far as I can see it) cannot use classes and the .each() function because every read more button has its own unique text. Is there any form of "for-loop" I could use to do the trick?

Thanks in advance!
Cheers Peter

Comment: You should rather navigate by the DOM structure, than by specific ids.

Comment: You can certainly use classes. You should also easily be able to combine `readmore` and `readless` into a single toggle. The exact details of how to best achieve such a function depends on what your DOM looks like. `data-` attributes could always be used, but knowledge of the DOM may reveal more convenient paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a `for` loop or jQuery's `each` could certainly be used to this end, classes appears to be your best option here. The exact implementation details would depend on what you know about your DOM, however.

For instance, if you are able to see to it that there will always be a container that encapsulates all the targeted elements, but none of the elements for another toggle, you may search for classes only within that container:

```
$('.toggle-read').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var container = $(this).closest('.read-container');
    container.find('.toggle-read, .read-more-text').toggle();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8m7ds9gb/)

There may be other layouts for which other assumptions can be made, and you would have to traverse the DOM in another manner, but that is the general idea. If, however, no assumptions can be made about the DOM, you may have to fall back to `data-` attributes. Such a solution could look something like this:

```
$('.toggle-read').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $($(this).data('target')).toggle();
    $($(this).data('other-button')).show();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Given the following markup:

```
<a href="#" id="readmore-1" class="toggle-read more" data-target="#moretext-1" data-other-button="#readless-1">Read more</a>
<a href="#" id="readless-1" class="toggle-read less" data-target="#moretext-1" data-other-button="#readmore-1">Read less</a>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e57gpnpj/)

Comment: As there will be no mixtures of containers, your first solution works just like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `readmoretext2` can be navigated to from `readmore2`. You should do that. E.g., if it is a child:

```
$('.readmore').click(function(){
    $(this).children('.readmoretext').toggle()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this,

```
$(".readmore").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('p').slideDown();
});
$(".readless").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('p').slideUp();
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/bv8yz9y3/)